# AngularJS value change not visible in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, prelink

I want to delay compiling child directive until a promise in parent directive's prelink will be resolved and value (CONFIG) will be overwritten.

In **Parent's** preLink:

```
    somePromise.then(function(){ 
       CONFIG = 1;
       elem.append($compile(template)(scope));
    }
```

Template contains **Child** directive, so Child's prelink is executing after promise's resolve.
Now I want to access CONFIG in **Child's** prelink and it has old value ({}).

Why is it happening?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/642/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `CONFIG = 1` in you directive, you are actually changing the value of a local variable, that happens to be the one injected by the Angular value service.

Since it is a local variable that you are changing, the contents injected at the child directive are unchanged.

In order to send a value to the child directive through the value service, you must do something like `CONFIG.value = 1`.

This works because despite being local variables (one for each directive), they are *references* to same service, thus changes at the pointed object are visible to both references.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to use angular.extend/angular.merge instead of direct assignment and now it works like a charm.